# Trailing slash on an ASP.NET MVC route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In the latest MVC preview, I'm using this route for a legacy URL:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Legacy-Firefox", // Route name
"Firefox-Extension/", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Firefox", id = "" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

The problem is that both of these URL's work:
http://example.com/Firefox-Extension
http://example.com/Firefox-Extension/

I only want the second to work (for SEO). Also, when I create a link to that page, the routing engine gives me back a URL without a trailing slash.

This is the code I'm using to generate the link:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Firefox Extension", "Firefox", "Home")%>
```

I believe can fix the first problem by using an HTTP handler to do a 301 redirect to the URL with the trailing slash. However, I want to link to the URL with the trailing slash, and I'm hoping to not have to hard-code the version with the slash.

Anyone know how to force the route to use a trailing slash?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a wrapper over RouteLink than there is an easy solution of the problem.
For example, I had a wrapper method RouteLinkEx:

```
public static string RouteLinkEx(this HtmlHelper helper,string text,string routeName,RouteValueDictionary rvd,object htmlAttributes)
      {

      UrlHelper uh = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext,helper.RouteCollection);
      // Add trailing slash to the url of the link
      string url = uh.RouteUrl(routeName,rvd) + "/";
      TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("a")
      {
        InnerHtml = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text) : string.Empty
      };
      builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
      builder.MergeAttribute("href",url);
      return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
      //---  
      }
```

As you see I used parameters to generate URL first. Then I added "/" at the end of the URL. and then I generated complete link using those URL.

Answer (score 3):

I happened across this blog post:

http://www.ytechie.com/2008/10/aspnet-mvc-what-about-seo.html

this morning before running into this question on StackOverflow.  That blog post (from the author of this question) has a trackback to this blog post from Scott Hanselman with an answer to this question:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCAndTheNewIIS7RewriteModule.aspx

I was surprised to find no link from here to there yet, so I just added it.  :)

Scott's answer suggests using URL Rewriting.

Answer (score 2):

When you write your links, you should always include the final slash.  I don't know if this applies to the mvc framework (or URL Routing in general), but I know that for static resources, if you don't put the slash in  you add a slight overhead as the request gets done twice.

The slash immediately identifies the url as pointing to a directory.  No need to parse files.

Again, I don't believe this applies when you use URL routing, but I haven't looked into it.

Check [HERE for an article about the trailing slash](http://dmiessler.com/study/hyperlink_trailing_slash/)

edit:
Upon thinking about this... I think it's probably better to leave off the slash, instead of trying to include it.  When you're using url routing, you're using the URL to route directly to a resource.  As opposed to pointing to a directory with an index.html or default.aspx, you're pointing to a specific file.

I know the difference is subtle, but it may be better to stick to the non-slash for Routed Urls, rather than fight with the framework.

Use a trailing slash strictly when you're actually pointing to a directory.  Thought I guess you could just append a slash to the end every time if you really didn't like it.

Comment: I agree, for new sites that's how I would do it. The problem is, I have an existing site I'm trying to convert.

Comment: I probably wouldn't spend too much time on it.  My guess is that Google is smart enough these days not to give you an SEO hit.

Answer (score 2):

MVC 5 and 6 has the option of generating lower case URL's for your routes. My route config is shown below:

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        // Imprive SEO by stopping duplicate URL's due to case or trailing slashes.
        routes.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

With this code, you should no longer need the canonicalize the URL's as this is done for you. One problem that can occur if you are using HTTP and HTTPS URL's and want a canonical URL for this. In this case, it's pretty easy to use the above approaches and replace HTTP with HTTPS or vice versa.

Another problem is external websites that link to your site may omit the trailing slash or add upper-case characters and for this you should perform a 301 permanent redirect to the correct URL with the trailing slash. For full usage and source code, refer to my [blog post](http://rehansaeed.com/canonical-urls-for-asp-net-mvc/) and the `RedirectToCanonicalUrlAttribute` filter:

```
/// <summary>
/// To improve Search Engine Optimization SEO, there should only be a single URL for each resource. Case 
/// differences and/or URL's with/without trailing slashes are treated as different URL's by search engines. This 
/// filter redirects all non-canonical URL's based on the settings specified to their canonical equivalent. 
/// Note: Non-canonical URL's are not generated by this site template, it is usually external sites which are 
/// linking to your site but have changed the URL case or added/removed trailing slashes.
/// (See Google's comments at http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html
/// and Bing's at http://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2012/01/26/moving-content-think-301-not-relcanonical).
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class RedirectToCanonicalUrlAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly bool appendTrailingSlash;
    private readonly bool lowercaseUrls;

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RedirectToCanonicalUrlAttribute" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="appendTrailingSlash">If set to <c>true</c> append trailing slashes, otherwise strip trailing 
    /// slashes.</param>
    /// <param name="lowercaseUrls">If set to <c>true</c> lower-case all URL's.</param>
    public RedirectToCanonicalUrlAttribute(
        bool appendTrailingSlash, 
        bool lowercaseUrls)
    {
        this.appendTrailingSlash = appendTrailingSlash;
        this.lowercaseUrls = lowercaseUrls;
    } 

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the HTTP request contains a non-canonical URL using <see cref="TryGetCanonicalUrl"/>, 
    /// if it doesn't calls the <see cref="HandleNonCanonicalRequest"/> method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">An object that encapsulates information that is required in order to use the 
    /// <see cref="RedirectToCanonicalUrlAttribute"/> attribute.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="filterContext"/> parameter is <c>null</c>.</exception>
    public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        if (string.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            string canonicalUrl;
            if (!this.TryGetCanonicalUrl(filterContext, out canonicalUrl))
            {
                this.HandleNonCanonicalRequest(filterContext, canonicalUrl);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Protected Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the specified URl is canonical and if it is not, outputs the canonical URL.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">An object that encapsulates information that is required in order to use the 
    /// <see cref="RedirectToCanonicalUrlAttribute" /> attribute.</param>
    /// <param name="canonicalUrl">The canonical URL.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if the URL is canonical, otherwise <c>false</c>.</returns>
    protected virtual bool TryGetCanonicalUrl(AuthorizationContext filterContext, out string canonicalUrl)
    {
        bool isCanonical = true;

        canonicalUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
        int queryIndex = canonicalUrl.IndexOf(QueryCharacter);

        if (queryIndex == -1)
        {
            bool hasTrailingSlash = canonicalUrl[canonicalUrl.Length - 1] == SlashCharacter;

            if (this.appendTrailingSlash)
            {
                // Append a trailing slash to the end of the URL.
                if (!hasTrailingSlash)
                {
                    canonicalUrl += SlashCharacter;
                    isCanonical = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Trim a trailing slash from the end of the URL.
                if (hasTrailingSlash)
                {
                    canonicalUrl = canonicalUrl.TrimEnd(SlashCharacter);
                    isCanonical = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            bool hasTrailingSlash = canonicalUrl[queryIndex - 1] == SlashCharacter;

            if (this.appendTrailingSlash)
            {
                // Append a trailing slash to the end of the URL but before the query string.
                if (!hasTrailingSlash)
                {
                    canonicalUrl = canonicalUrl.Insert(queryIndex, SlashCharacter.ToString());
                    isCanonical = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Trim a trailing slash to the end of the URL but before the query string.
                if (hasTrailingSlash)
                {
                    canonicalUrl = canonicalUrl.Remove(queryIndex - 1, 1);
                    isCanonical = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (this.lowercaseUrls)
        {
            foreach (char character in canonicalUrl)
            {
                if (char.IsUpper(character))
                {
                    canonicalUrl = canonicalUrl.ToLower();
                    isCanonical = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return isCanonical;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles HTTP requests for URL's that are not canonical. Performs a 301 Permanent Redirect to the canonical URL.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">An object that encapsulates information that is required in order to use the 
    /// <see cref="RedirectToCanonicalUrlAttribute" /> attribute.</param>
    /// <param name="canonicalUrl">The canonical URL.</param>
    protected virtual void HandleNonCanonicalRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext, string canonicalUrl)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(canonicalUrl, true);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Usage example to ensure all requests are 301 redirected to the correct canonical URL:

```
filters.Add(new RedirectToCanonicalUrlAttribute(
    RouteTable.Routes.AppendTrailingSlash, 
    RouteTable.Routes.LowercaseUrls));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a overload for RouteLinkEx(HtmlHelper, string,string, object)

```
        public static string RouteLinkEx(this HtmlHelper helper, string text, string routeName, object routeValues)
    {

        UrlHelper uh = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);

        // Add trailing slash to the url of the link 
        string url = uh.RouteUrl(routeName, routeValues) + "/";
        TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("a")
        {
            InnerHtml = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text) : string.Empty
        };
        //builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        builder.MergeAttribute("href", url);
        return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        //---   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version for ASP.NET MVC 2

```
    public static MvcHtmlString RouteLinkEx(this HtmlHelper helper, string text, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
    {
        return RouteLinkEx(helper, text, null, routeValues, null);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString RouteLinkEx(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string text, string routeName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        string url = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(routeName, null, null, null, null, null, routeValues, htmlHelper.RouteCollection, htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, false);

        var builder = new TagBuilder("a")
        {
            InnerHtml = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text) : string.Empty
        };
        builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        // Add trailing slash to the url of the link
        builder.MergeAttribute("href", url + "/");
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are solving the problem from the wrong angle.  The reason given for wanting to force the single url is for SEO.  I believe this refers to getting a duplicate content penalty because search engines consider this two URLs with the same content.

Another solution to this problem then is to add a CANONICAL tag to your page which tells the search engines which is the "official" url for the page.  Once you do that you no longer need to force the URLs and search engines will not penalize you and will route search results to your official url.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en