# Trailing slash confusing AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax

I have a page with several Update Panels on it.  the url of that page is:
http://[domainnamehere]/stores/

If I omit the trailing slash, everything works fine.  if I include it, when the page does an asynchronous postback, it goes to http://[domainnamehere]/stores/**stores**

Not sure why that's happening, but its sure a pain in the butt!  Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is on the server-side.  You need to configure the route to your resource to accept the trailing slash.  If you are using MVC you should be able to add a slash to that route, if not it will require URL rewriting at the IIS level.

Comment: Marteljn, thanks for your quick answer.  i'm certain you're right, what i'm not sure of is how to go about configuring my route to accept the trailing slash.  I thought i already had by putting the trailing slash in the route: 'routes.Add("LocatorRoute2", new Route("Stores/", new CustomRouteHandler("/Locator.aspx")));'

Comment: Did a little more googling and apparently this is a fairly coomm complaint without a good solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027027/why-is-asp-net-mvc-ignoring-my-trailing-slash, this post points to a blog that discusses how to fix it using URL rewriting (assuming you are using IIS7).  There are ISAPI filters for IIS6 that should be able to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, i don't feel quite so dumb if nobody else can completely solve it either :)

Comment: You could also in the  `Application_BeginRequest` event of the Global.asax, do a redirect if the request path ends with a slash, but that is a hack.  But it may be the easiest fix.